# python pandas: Remove duplicates by columns A, which is not satisfying a condition in column B

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with repeat values in column A. I want to drop duplicates, keeping the row which has its value > 0 in column B

So this:

```
A B
1 20
1 10
1 -3
2 30
2 -9
2 40
3 10
```

Should turn into this:

```
A B
1 20
1 10
2 30
2 40
3 10
```

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved? I shall be grateful!

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates in `A`, or just filter `B` to be >0? Your desired output doesn't look like any duplicates have been removed.

Comment: If values in A are duplicate, only then we need to drop those duplicate rows which has its value in B not greater than 0.

Comment: So if you had another row where `A = 4` and `B = -7`, you would keep this row because there is no duplicate in `A`?

Answer (score 0):

In sample data are not duplciates, so use only:

```
df = df[df['B'].gt(0)]
print (df)
   A   B
0  1  20
1  1  10
3  2  30
5  2  40
6  3  10
```

If there are duplicates:

```
print (df)
   A   B
0  1  20
1  1  10
2  1  10
3  1  10
4  1  -3
5  2  30
6  2  -9
7  2  40
8  3  10

df = df[df['B'].gt(0) & ~df.duplicated()]
print (df)
   A   B
0  1  20
1  1  10
5  2  30
7  2  40
8  3  10
```